# How to validate material-ui-phone-number with Yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form

I am trying to validate a `material-ui-phone-number` field with YUP but when I had the inputRef prop to the component YUP triggers an error saying `TypeError: e is undefined`.
It seems that the `material-ui-phone-number` component is sending the value and YUP is expecting an event (`e.target.value`)

[You can check sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cdn-glqf1?file=/src/App.js:0-1317)

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers";
import * as yup from "yup";

const Step1Schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required("O campo nome é obrigatório"),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required("O campo email é obrigatório")
    .email("Formato de email inválido"),
  phone: yup.mixed().test((value) => console.log(value))
});

const Step1 = ({ formData, nextStep, formStepData }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(Step1Schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  return (
    <div data-aos="fade-up" id="house-form">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <MuiPhoneNumber
          id="contactPhoneNumber"
          inputRef={register}
          defaultCountry={"pt"}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          name="phone"
          label="Contacto telefónico"
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          value={phone}
          onChange={(value) => setPhone(value)}
          error={Boolean(errors.phone)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Step1;
```

Comment: seems you need to pass it as `ref={register}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
If I do that YUP doesn't read it's value, sorry I forgot to add a submit button, I'll add it now

Comment: @japrescott, 
Sorry, but according to https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#integratingwithuilibraries  you should use inputRef instead of ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `Controller` component to integrate with any third-party input components that do not work out-of-the-box with `react-hook-form`.

```js
const { control, ... } = useForm();

...

<Controller
  name="phone"
  control={control}
  render={({ name, onBlur, onChange, value }) => (
    <MuiPhoneNumber
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      // onChange pass the raw value so you can access it using e instead of
      // e.target.value. props.onChange can accept the value directly
      onChange={onChange}
      {...}
    />
  )}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64024619/how-to-validate-material-ui-phone-number-with-yup/]

Comment: Man you are a saviour. Thanks a lot.
I had already tried with a Controller but I was missing that onChange prop. Awesome!!

Comment: I've used the same approach but with helper text for errors. It's not working properly since the helper text appears but never actually goes away, even after typing the correct input. Is it something to do with validation? Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb).